# Como obtener el valor de la tabla llamando desde php?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
<table border=7 ALIGN=CENTER width="70%" bgcolor=#ffffff>

<form role="form" name="registro" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="vehi-consul.php" method="post"> 

    <TR ALIGN=CENTER> 
        <th><label for="descve">Selecci&oacute;n por Nombre: </label></th>
<?php
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

?>
<td><select>    
    <?php    
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
    {   
        ?>  

        <option value=" <?php $row['descve']; ?> " selected>
        <?php echo $row['descve']; ?>
        </option>

        <?php
    }  
    ?> 

</td>

<TD><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"></TD>
</form>
</TR>
</table>
```

Anexo el archivo `vehi-consul.php`

```
<?php

    require('conexion.php');

    $vclave = $_POST['vclave'];

    $query="SELECT vclave, descve, tipove, placasve, anoplacasve, captank, cambioaceite, afinacionve, segurove, vensegurove, fotove, usuario, km1, km2, km1r, km2r, diasrca, diasram, chofer FROM vehiculos WHERE descve LIKE '%$vclave%'";

    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

    $rows = $resultado->num_rows;
?> 
<?php  $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");

$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select vclave, descve, tipove, placasve, anoplacasve, captank, cambioaceite, afinacionve, segurove, vensegurove, fotove, usuario, km1, km2, km1r, km2r, diasrca, diasram, chofer
                        from vehiculos where vclave='$_POST[vclave]' or descve='$_POST[vclave]' or descve='$row[descve]' or descve='$_POST[descve]' ")  or
            die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error($conexion));

$cant=0;

while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{

    echo '<br>Descve REQUEST:', $_REQUEST['descve'];
    echo '<br>Descve POST:', $_POST['descve'];
    echo '<br>Descve GET:', $_GET['descve'];
    echo '<br>Descve:', $descve; 
?>

<table border=7 ALIGN=CENTER width="100%" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<thead ALIGN=CENTER>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Clave   </b></td>
    <td colspan="4" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Descripci&oacute;n   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Tipo de Veh&iacute;culo    </b></td>
    <td colspan="1" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Chofer    </b></td>
    <td  colspan="1" bgcolor=#0080FF><a href="vehi-elim.php?vclave=<?php echo $reg['vclave'];?>" onclick="return confirm('&#191;Est&aacute;s seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?');">Eliminar</a></td> 
    <td  colspan="1" bgcolor=#0080FF><a href="vehi-mod.php?vclave=<?php echo $reg['vclave'];?>">Modificar</a></td>                  
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $reg['vclave'];?></td>
    <td colspan="4"><?php echo $reg['descve'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['tipove'];?></td>

    <!--LINK PARA CHOFERES--> 
    <td colspan="1">

<form action="../chofconsul.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="chofer" value="<?php echo $reg['chofer']; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $reg['chofer']; ?>" />
</form>

</td>   

    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" align=center><img width="250" height="200" src="php/images/<?php echo $reg['fotove'];?>" /></td>    
</tr>

<tr BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
    <td colspan="3"><b>   Placas   </b></td>
    <td><b>   A&ntilde;o de las placas  </b></td>
    <td><b>   Capacidad del Tanque  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Usuario   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Seguro del Vehiculo  </b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>   Vencimiento del seguro   </b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $reg['placasve'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['anoplacasve'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['captank'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['usuario'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['segurove'];?></td>
    <td colspan="1"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha5=$reg['vensegurove'];
        $fecha6=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha5));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha6;
    ?></td> 
</tr>

</tr>

<tr BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
    <td colspan="4"><b>   Cambio de Aceite   </b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>   KM del &uacute;ltimo Cambio de Aceite   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Realizar Cambio de Aceite en:  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor  </b></td>
    <td><b>   KM de la &uacute;ltima Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Realizar Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor en:  </b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha1=$reg['cambioaceite'];
        $fecha2=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha1));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha2;
    ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $reg['km1'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['km1r'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['diasrca'],' días';?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha3=$reg['afinacionve'];
        $fecha4=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha3));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha4;
    ?></td> 

    <td><?php echo $reg['km2'],' Km';?></td>
    <td colspan="1"><?php echo $reg['km2r'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['diasram'], ' días';?></td>

<tr>  
    <td  colspan="12" bgcolor=#0080FF></td> 
</tr>

</table>
<br>

<?php

$cant++;

}

if ($cant==0)
{

  echo '<br><h1>',"Clave o Nombre no existente.",'</h1><br>';


  // Se muestra en pantalla las diversas variables que manejo para ver si mustra alguna.
  echo '<br>Descve REQUEST:', $_REQUEST['descve'];
  echo '<br>Descve POST:', $_POST['descve'];
  echo '<br>Descve GET:', $_GET['descve'];
  echo '<br>Descve:', $descve;
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Me muestra en la lista toda la información de la base de datos. Cuando le doy a aceptar me manda a la página designada pero me muestra el último archivo de la tabla y no el que le pedí.

¿Podrían orientarme con este dilema? Muchas gracias

***EDITO:***

Ha quedado resuelto, dejo el código funcionando por si a alguien le llegara a servir.

```
<?php   // Este es el archivo vehi-consul.php

    require('conexion.php');

    $descve = $_POST[descve];

    $query="SELECT vclave, descve, tipove, placasve, anoplacasve, captank, cambioaceite, afinacionve, segurove, vensegurove, fotove, usuario, km1, km2, km1r, km2r, diasrca, diasram, chofer FROM vehiculos WHERE descve LIKE '%$vclave%'";

    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

    $rows = $resultado->num_rows;
?>

<?php




$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") or
    die("Problemas con la conexión");

$registros=mysqli_query($conexion,"select vclave, descve, tipove, placasve, anoplacasve, captank, cambioaceite, afinacionve, segurove, vensegurove, fotove, usuario, km1, km2, km1r, km2r, diasrca, diasram, chofer
                        from vehiculos where vclave='$vclave' or descve='$_POST[descve]' or descve='$descve' ")  or
            die("Problemas en el select:".mysqli_error($conexion));

$cant=0;


while ($reg=mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{

//echo '<br>Descve REQUEST:', $_REQUEST['descve'];
//echo '<br>Descve POST:', $_POST['descve'];
//echo '<br>Descve GET:', $_GET['descve'];
//echo '<br>Descve:', $descve;

?>

<table border=7 ALIGN=CENTER width="100%" bgcolor=#ffffff>
<thead ALIGN=CENTER>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Clave   </b></td>
    <td colspan="4" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Descripci&oacute;n   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Tipo de Veh&iacute;culo    </b></td>
    <td colspan="1" BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0"><b>   Chofer    </b></td>
    <td  colspan="1" bgcolor=#0080FF><a href="vehi-elim.php?vclave=<?php echo $reg['vclave'];?>" onclick="return confirm('&#191;Est&aacute;s seguro que deseas eliminar el registro?');">Eliminar</a></td> 
    <td  colspan="1" bgcolor=#0080FF><a href="vehi-mod.php?vclave=<?php echo $reg['vclave'];?>">Modificar</a></td>                  
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $reg['vclave'];?></td>
    <td colspan="4"><?php echo $reg['descve'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['tipove'];?></td>

    <!--LINK PARA CHOFERES--> 
    <td colspan="1">

<form action="../chofconsul.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="chofer" value="<?php echo $reg['chofer']; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $reg['chofer']; ?>" />
</form>

</td>   

    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" align=center><img width="250" height="200" src="php/images/<?php echo $reg['fotove'];?>" /></td>    
</tr>

<tr BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
    <td colspan="3"><b>   Placas   </b></td>
    <td><b>   A&ntilde;o de las placas  </b></td>
    <td><b>   Capacidad del Tanque  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Usuario   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Seguro del Vehiculo  </b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>   Vencimiento del seguro   </b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $reg['placasve'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['anoplacasve'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['captank'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['usuario'];?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $reg['segurove'];?></td>
    <td colspan="1"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha5=$reg['vensegurove'];
        $fecha6=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha5));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha6;
    ?></td> 
</tr>

</tr>

<tr BGCOLOR="#F0F0F0">
    <td colspan="4"><b>   Cambio de Aceite   </b></td>
    <td colspan="1"><b>   KM del &uacute;ltimo Cambio de Aceite   </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Realizar Cambio de Aceite en:  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor  </b></td>
    <td><b>   KM de la &uacute;ltima Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor  </b></td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>   Realizar Afinaci&oacute;n Mayor en:  </b></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha1=$reg['cambioaceite'];
        $fecha2=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha1));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha2;
    ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $reg['km1'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['km1r'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['diasrca'],' días';?></td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php
        //formato fecha americana
        $fecha3=$reg['afinacionve'];
        $fecha4=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha3));
        //El nuevo valor de la variable: $fecha2="20-10-2008"
        echo $fecha4;
    ?></td> 

    <td><?php echo $reg['km2'],' Km';?></td>
    <td colspan="1"><?php echo $reg['km2r'],' Km';?></td>
    <td><?php echo $reg['diasram'], ' días';?></td>

<tr>  
    <td  colspan="12" bgcolor=#0080FF></td> 
</tr>

</table>
<br>

<?php


$cant++;

}

if ($cant==0)
{

  echo '<br><h1>',"Clave o Nombre no existente.",'</h1><br>';

}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>



//Codigo de Option Value


<center><h1>Busqueda de Veh&iacute;culo</h1></center>

<table border=7 ALIGN=CENTER width="70%" bgcolor=#ffffff>

<form role="form" name="descve" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="vehi-consul.php" method="POST"> 

    <TR ALIGN=CENTER> 
        <th><label for="descve">Selecci&oacute;n por Nombre: </label></th>
<?php
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

?>   
<td><select name="descve">    
    <?php    
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
    {   
        ?>  

        <option value="<?php echo $row['descve']; ?>" >
        <?php echo $row['descve']; ?>
        </option>

        <?php

    }  
    ?> 



</select>
</td>

<TD><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"></TD>
</form>
</TR>
</table>
```

Comment: Yo creo que debes colocar también que Variables estas enviando a tu archivo ***vehi-consul.php*** y de esta forma como estas recibiendo las variables en ese mismo archivo. Es necesario esa información, si estas haciendo un **SQL** donde consultas el detalle de tu articulo, también debes agregar el **SQL**.

Comment: Muy cierto, anexo codigo del archivo vehi-consul.php

Comment: Tu codigo es vulnerable a SQL injections. Eso es GRAVE. Cualquiera que pueda acceder a la pagina web puede llegar a alterar o borrar la base de datos. JAMAS subas este código a un sitio público.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, podrías darme algunos consejos de como proteger programas para que no sean vulnerables, por favor.

Comment: lo retirare por cierto.

Comment: @Stravos77 Nunca armar consultas de SQL concatenando strings que proveen directamente del formulario (POST o GET). Usar siempre (tiene otras ventajas, ademas de la seguridad) "prepared statements"  Por ejemplo: http://itfreekzone.blogspot.com.ar/2011/04/como-evitar-sql-injection-prepared.html

Comment: @Stravos77 Deberías añadir la solución como una respuesta, y marcártela a ti mismo como válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, observando tu código he notado lo siguiente:

1. Haces una consulta para listar todos tu items (productos, autos, lo que sea) y al parecer todo esto esta correcto.
2. Cuando su envías tu formulario NO le estas indicando que item quieres elegir y entonces es aquí donde habita el problema, es decir, estas asignando un valor a tu **option** del menú tipo select, pero este menú NO tiene ninguna nombre para que la variable del option sea enviada.

Solución:

Debes asignar la variable; `vclave` a tu menú tipo select. Algo como: `<select name="vclave">`. Prueba con esto y veamos que sucede.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu comentario, lo he probado e incluso puse varios tipos de variables uno por vez pero nada, crees que deba modificar alguna otra parte del código? muchas gracias por tu apoyo.

Comment: Pero el Select ya tiene name?

Comment: Si le puse el nombre.

Comment: Que errores te arroja, ya debugueaste? proporciona toda la información posible.

Comment: He buscado errores con esto, error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');   Pero la verdad todo lo hago en el block de notas.

Comment: Alonso, neta no preguntes como le hice porque le pique a muchas cosas, bueno cambie varias, pero ya quedo, voy a poner el código funcionando por si a alguien le puede servir, te agradezco mucho el apoyo que me brindaste, te envío saludos y bendiciones.